# Going to the next Input Field using enter key instead of tab key for pypsimplegui

Tags: python

I have created a form using pypsimplegui for manual input of some data.
Noticed that the default setting is to use tab button to move to the next input field.
I like to change to use enter key to move to the next input field.

Does anyone know how to get about to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to my question. First we use window.bind and follow by an event =='Return'.

```
window = sg.Window("Verification Inspection Records",[[sg.Menu(menu_layout)],
            [sg.Text("              Verification Inspection Records               ", size=(None, None), font=("Arial",30,'bold'), text_color="Dark Blue", background_color="white" )],
            [sg.Text("", size=(None, None), font=("Arial",5, 'bold'),)],
            [sg.Text("Inspected By:", size=(15,None), font=("Arial",18)), sg.Input(size=(30,None), font=("Arial",18), key='employee_id')],
            [sg.Text("", size=(None, None), font=("Arial",5, 'bold'),)],
            [sg.Text("Inspection Layer:", size=(15,None), font=("Arial",18)), sg.InputCombo(process_list,key='inspect_layer', size=(30,None), font=("Arial",18))],   
            #[sg.Text("", size=(None, None), font=("Arial",5, 'bold'),)],
            [sg.Text("ID:", size=(15,None), font=("Arial",18)), sg.Input(key='id', size=(30,None), font=("Arial",18))],],
         
            [sg.Output(size=(77, 5), font=("Arial",12), text_color='red',key="output")]
        ],finalize=True)
    
    window.bind("<Return>", "Return")    
        while True:
                    event, values = win.read()
                    if event in (None, "Exit"):
                        break
                    elif event =='Return':
                        user_event = win.user_bind_event
                        user_event.widget.tk_focusNext().focus()
```